# Arduino/MySQL Connector unable to connect using UIPEthernet with ENC28J60

Tags: c++, mysql, arduino, ethernet

## The Context

I've been working on a very specific case of an Arduino UNO that MUST connect directly through Ethernet to a local (LAN) Windows Server that hosts a MySQL database.
The task is really simple, just validate some IDs in that database from the Arduino.

The hard part is that i'm absolutely **NOT allowed to access nor modify the Server**, obliterating any hope of hosting a mini API/PHP Script, handle the MySQL Connection locally to that PC, and make HTTP requests to it.

Thus I decided to use [Arduino/MySQL Connector](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino) which is designed to do exactly that. However, after some research I found out that it uses the default `Ethernet` Library which does not supports the `ENC28J60` Mini Eth-Shield.

Further research led me to a [tiny hint](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino/issues/31) that should make `Arduino/MySQL Connector` compatible to `UIPEthernet` Library, which also is compatible with the aforementioned shield.

### The Problem

#### UPDATE 3

[Github Issue](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino/issues/135)

I've been tweaking the program and libraries a bit more, setting UIPEthernet to disable UDP and beginning the program connection as static saved a lot of memory.

> Sketch uses 19182 bytes (59%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
> Global variables use 1346 bytes (65%) of dynamic memory, leaving 702 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

Now that the program flows without getting memory-leaked to death, I can see that I'm clearly facing a connectivity problem. If it is originated on an unknown incompatability between the two libraries, I don't know.

```
18:00:47.074 -> Connecting
18:00:47.074 -> ...trying...
18:01:12.049 -> ...got: 0 retrying...
18:01:12.546 -> ...trying...
18:01:37.607 -> ...got: 0 retrying...
18:01:38.104 -> ...trying...
18:02:03.165 -> ...got: 0 retrying...
18:02:03.661 -> Connection Failed
```

I've tested the connection in every possible way from other devices in LAN and it works perfectly.

Current state of the program:

```
#include <UIPEthernet.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server_addr(192, 168, 1, 8);
char user[] = "god";
char password[] = "ishallpass";
char default_db[] = "databasename";
char query[] = "SELECT nombre_cliente FROM databasename.clientes WHERE id = 1";

EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  Ethernet.begin(mac_addr, server_addr);
  Serial.println(F("Connecting"));
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password, default_db)) {
    delay(1000);
    row_values *row = NULL;
    char* nombre_cliente;
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(F("Querying"));
    MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
    cur_mem->execute(query);
    column_names *columns = cur_mem->get_columns();
    do {
      row = cur_mem->get_next_row();
      if (row != NULL) {
        nombre_cliente = row->values[0];
      } else {
        Serial.println(F("Error querying"));
      }
    } while (row != NULL);
    delete cur_mem;
    Serial.print(F("name: "));
    Serial.println(nombre_cliente);
    delay(500);
  }
  else
    Serial.println(F("Connection Failed"));
}

void loop() {
}
```

***EDIT:***
This is the full `UIPEthernet` logging with `ACTLOGLEVEL` set to `LOG_DEBUG`

(`LOG_DEBUG_V3` seems to be *infinite* lol)

```
18:40:42.573 -> Connecting
18:40:42.573 -> ...trying...
18:40:43.003 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-58]: 70FA
18:40:43.003 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:40:43.003 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 FF FF FF FF FF FF DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 1 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 C0 A8 1 8 
18:40:43.500 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [6-42], next: 46, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:43.533 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:43.533 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:43.533 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:43.533 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:43.533 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:45
18:40:43.996 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-58]: 70FA
18:40:43.996 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:40:43.996 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 FF FF FF FF FF FF DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 1 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 C0 A8 1 8 
18:40:44.162 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [4C-96], next: 9A, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:44.162 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:44.195 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:44.195 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:44.195 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:44.195 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 99F3
18:40:44.195 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:44.195 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 3 0 0 40 6 F7 65 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 24 1F 49 3 24 2C C5 C6 A 34 A1 50 14 FF FF C 66 0 0 
18:40:44.228 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:44.228 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:99
18:40:45.188 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [A0-EA], next: EE, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:45.188 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:45.188 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:45.221 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:45.221 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:45.221 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: DA90
18:40:45.221 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:45.221 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 4 0 0 40 6 F7 64 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 24 1F 49 3 24 2C C5 C6 FC D0 EF 50 14 FF FF 6F 25 0 0 
18:40:45.254 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:45.254 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:ED
18:40:45.751 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-58]: 70FA
18:40:45.751 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:40:45.751 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 FF FF FF FF FF FF DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 1 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 C0 A8 1 8 
18:40:45.784 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [F4-1A4], next: 1A8, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:45.784 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=176
18:40:45.784 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:45.817 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 176
18:40:45.817 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-66]: 267B
18:40:45.817 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_packet(255)[66-176]: FFFF
18:40:45.817 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 20D3
18:40:45.817 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:45.817 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 6 0 0 40 6 F7 67 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 7E 1F 49 F3 6E 5E 68 B9 F1 22 C8 50 14 1 36 2C DF 0 0 
18:40:45.850 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:45.850 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:1A7
18:40:45.949 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [1AE-1EA], next: 1EE, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:45.982 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:45.982 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:45.982 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:45.982 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:45.982 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:46.015 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:1ED
18:40:46.181 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [1F4-230], next: 234, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:46.181 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:46.181 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:46.181 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:46.181 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:46.214 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:46.214 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:233
18:40:46.578 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [23A-276], next: 27A, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:46.611 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:46.611 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:46.611 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:46.611 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:46.611 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:46.611 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:279
18:40:47.075 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [280-2BC], next: 2C0, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:47.075 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:47.075 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:47.075 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:47.108 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:47.108 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:2BF
18:40:47.207 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [2C6-310], next: 314, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:47.207 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:47.207 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:47.207 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:47.207 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:47.207 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 75C2
18:40:47.240 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:47.240 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 7 0 0 40 6 F7 61 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 24 1F 49 3 24 2C C5 C8 DD 0 AA 50 14 FF FF 3D 8A 0 0 
18:40:47.273 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:47.273 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:313
18:40:47.406 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [31A-356], next: 35A, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:47.439 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:47.439 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:47.439 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:47.439 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:47.439 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:47.439 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:359
18:40:49.032 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-58]: 70FA
18:40:49.032 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:40:49.032 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 FF FF FF FF FF FF DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 1 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 C0 A8 1 8 
18:40:49.098 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [360-39C], next: 3A0, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:49.098 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:49.098 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:49.098 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:49.098 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:49.098 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:49.131 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:39F
18:40:51.283 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [3A6-3F0], next: 3F4, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:51.283 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:51.283 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:51.283 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:51.283 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:51.283 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 9C5F
18:40:51.316 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:51.316 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 9 0 0 40 6 F7 5F C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 24 1F 49 3 24 2C C5 CC A7 9A 6 50 14 FF FF A0 63 0 0 
18:40:51.316 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:51.349 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:3F3
18:40:52.541 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [3FA-436], next: 43A, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:52.541 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:52.541 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:52.574 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:52.574 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:52.574 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:52.574 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:439
18:40:54.097 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [440-47C], next: 480, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:54.097 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:54.097 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:54.130 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type ARP, uip_len: 60
18:40:54.130 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:40:54.130 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 2 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 54 60 9 0 4 CE C0 A8 1 A 
18:40:54.130 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:54.163 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:47F
18:40:55.289 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-58]: 70FA
18:40:55.289 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:40:55.289 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 FF FF FF FF FF FF DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 1 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 C0 A8 1 8 
18:40:55.785 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [486-4C2], next: 4C6, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:55.785 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:55.785 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:55.785 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:55.785 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:55.785 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:55.819 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:4C5
18:40:55.819 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [4CC-516], next: 51A, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:55.819 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:55.819 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:55.852 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:55.852 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:55.852 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 6F85
18:40:55.852 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:55.852 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 B 0 0 40 6 F7 62 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 86 1F 49 80 8C F A5 1 DE 17 6E 50 14 38 90 7A 90 0 0 
18:40:55.885 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:55.885 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:519
18:40:56.448 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [520-55C], next: 560, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:56.448 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:56.481 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:56.481 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:56.481 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:56.481 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:55F
18:40:56.481 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [566-5A2], next: 5A6, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:56.481 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:56.514 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:56.514 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type ARP, uip_len: 60
18:40:56.514 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:56.514 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:5A5
18:40:56.812 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [5AC-5F6], next: 5FA, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:56.812 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:56.812 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:56.812 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:56.845 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:56.845 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: C5A9
18:40:56.845 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:56.845 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 C 0 0 40 6 F7 61 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 86 1F 49 80 8C F A5 2 D4 3A CE 50 14 38 90 56 3A 0 0 
18:40:56.878 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:56.878 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:5F9
18:40:58.798 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [600-64A], next: 64E, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:58.798 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:40:58.798 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:58.831 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:40:58.831 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:40:58.831 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 534B
18:40:58.831 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:40:58.831 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 D 0 0 40 6 F7 60 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 86 1F 49 80 8C F A5 4 AE DA 81 50 14 38 90 B4 AC 0 0 
18:40:58.864 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:58.864 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:64D
18:40:59.195 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [654-690], next: 694, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:59.195 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:59.228 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:59.228 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:59.228 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: FFFF
18:40:59.228 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:40:59.228 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:693
18:40:59.990 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [69A-6D6], next: 6DA, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:40:59.990 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=60
18:40:59.990 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:40:59.990 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 60
18:40:59.990 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:00.023 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:6D9
18:41:03.035 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [6E0-72A], next: 72E, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:41:03.035 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:41:03.068 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:41:03.068 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:41:03.068 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:41:03.068 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 79E8
18:41:03.068 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:41:03.068 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 E 0 0 40 6 F7 5F C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 86 1F 49 80 8C F A5 8 A1 73 B5 50 14 38 90 17 86 0 0 
18:41:03.101 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:03.101 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:72D
18:41:04.293 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [734-77E], next: 782, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:41:04.293 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:41:04.326 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:41:04.326 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:41:04.326 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:41:04.326 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: C043
18:41:04.326 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:41:04.326 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 F 0 0 40 6 F7 59 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 28 1F 49 F4 1B 40 B6 24 82 21 63 50 14 FF FF BC 3F 0 0 
18:41:04.359 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:04.359 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:781
18:41:05.320 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [788-7D2], next: 7D6, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:41:05.320 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:41:05.320 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:41:05.353 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:41:05.353 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:41:05.353 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 33BF
18:41:05.353 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:41:05.353 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 10 0 0 40 6 F7 58 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 28 1F 49 F4 1B 40 B6 25 73 9B E5 50 14 FF FF 40 CC 0 0 
18:41:05.386 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:05.386 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:7D5
18:41:05.750 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [7DC-26], next: 2A, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:41:05.783 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:41:05.783 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:41:05.783 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:41:05.783 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:41:05.783 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: C83E
18:41:05.783 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:41:05.783 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 11 0 0 40 6 F7 5C C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 8A 1F 49 3 9 F9 A0 B7 D0 AE 57 50 14 38 90 C1 37 0 0 
18:41:05.817 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:05.817 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:29
18:41:06.776 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [30-7A], next: 7E, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:41:06.776 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:41:06.809 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:41:06.809 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:41:06.809 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:41:06.809 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 10AF
18:41:06.809 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:41:06.809 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 54 60 9 0 4 CE DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 12 0 0 40 6 F7 5B C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 A B0 8A 1F 49 3 9 F9 A0 B8 C4 1D AC 50 14 38 90 50 EF 0 0 
18:41:06.842 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:06.842 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:7D
18:41:07.339 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG:receivePacket [84-CE], next: D2, stat: C0, Packet count: 1 -> OK
18:41:07.339 -> Enc28J60Network::receivePacket(void) DEBUG: rxstat OK. receivePkt.size=74
18:41:07.339 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:receivePacket: 255
18:41:07.339 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:readPacket type IP, uip_len: 74
18:41:07.339 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-74]: FFFF
18:41:07.372 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 10C0
18:41:07.372 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 54, packet: 1
18:41:07.372 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-836]: 0 AE 84 C6 A9 5D 15 DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 0 45 0 0 28 0 13 0 0 40 6 F7 55 C0 A8 1 8 C0 A8 1 F D6 28 1F 49 F4 1B 40 B6 27 54 9A E1 50 14 FF FF 3F EF 0 0 
18:41:07.405 -> UIPEthernetClass::tick() DEBUG:freeing packet: 255
18:41:07.405 -> Enc28J60Network::setERXRDPT(void) DEBUG:Set actnextPacketPtr:D1
18:41:07.637 -> uip_tcpchksum(void) DEBUG:uip_buf[34-54]: 7AE6
18:41:07.637 -> UIPEthernetClass::network_send() DEBUG:uip_buf (uip_len): 42, packet: 1
18:41:07.670 -> Enc28J60Network::sendPacket(memhandle handle) DEBUG:sendPacket(1) [800-82A]: 0 FF FF FF FF FF FF DE AD BE EF FE ED 8 6 0 1 8 0 6 4 0 1 DE AD BE EF FE ED C0 A8 1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 C0 A8 1 8 
18:41:07.670 -> ...got: 0 retrying...
18:41:08.166 -> ...trying...
```

Comment: did you try the UIPEthernet library with some simple examples like a WebServer?

Comment: After some more testing it somehow managed to connect. However, i'm now getting a low memory warning from arduino and a memory error from the mysql connector, see response

Comment: I don't know much about the Arduino architecture, nor the internals of MySQL connector, but gut feeling tells me that it is too heavy to use on an embedded platform like that.

Comment: @mukunda yes, I share that feeling. However it may be fixable because it's the buffer variable the one that gets what it feels like logical noise coming from the connection. Maybe, just maybe, if we find the reason of that we might also solve the dynamic memory problem in one shot. There is an allocated memory call right there maybe it is a simple encoding/stream lifecycle problem, even a response access problem when trying to get the target string (which is "fernando" btw)

Comment: use `MySQL_Cursor cur_mem(&conn);`. use F() macro for strings

Comment: @Juraj I will try that way to instance the cursor, but i can only guess that you are suggesting it to reduce memory consumption, am i right?. Also, i'm already using F() in every serial print. Can i use it in other place of that code?

Comment: @Juraj changing `MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);` for `MySQL_Cursor cur_mem(&conn);` raises an exception

Comment: dynamic memory allocations fragament the heap until there is no continuous space left

Comment: Solved the memory issues. Now the problem is narrowed to a connectivity issue, thanks!

Comment: i've been thinkering with this connector for way too much time now. I've got an Arduino Friendly W5100 Eth Shield and it works not only way better but also the library stack occupies about a 60% less

Answer (score 0):

## For posterity..

LOTS testing and error made by myself and even with the `Arduino/MySQL Connection` developer clearly pointed out that the `ENC28J60` is not powerful nor fast enough to handle such connections and should be avoided.

The workaround was simple enough, **use Arduino-friendly Ethernet Shields.**

### My workaround

Further development of the project led to the refactor from a direct `MySQL/Ethernet` connection to a pure `HTTP API:REST` connection using:

- Arduino Sketch that only uses the default `Ethernet.h` combined with [a very helpful](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient) `ArduinoHttpClient.h` library.
- A very careful HTTP request/response control.
- Server Side hosted PHP scripts, which in turn are responsible to connect to the database and return the data to the Arduino.

As a result a single Arduino is now capable of hosting a simple control panel website, which also logs real-time data to an SD and a remote database, and Controls several peripherals.

#### Examples

- Arduino Side

  ```
  //... IMPORTS AND CONFIG
  byte MAC_ADDR[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
  char DB_SERVER_ADDR[] = "192.168.0.21";
  IPAddress ARDUINO_IP(192, 168, 0, 19);
  EthernetClient arduinoClient;
  EthernetServer arduinoServer(80);
  HttpClient arduinoHttpClient = HttpClient(arduinoClient, DB_SERVER_ADDR, 80);

  //... DATA DOWNLOAD
  void downloadClients()
  {
    printlnData(F("INFO Downloading data..."), true);
    arduinoHttpClient.get("/arduino.php");
    if (arduinoHttpClient.responseStatusCode() == 200)
    {
      String response = arduinoHttpClient.responseBody();
      printlnData(response, true);
      if (response.length() > 0)
      {
        clients = response;
      }
      printlnData(String("INFO downloaded data size = ") + sizeof(clients) + "bytes", true);
    }
    else
    {
      delay(1000);
      reconnect(true);
    }
  }

  //... REMOTE CHECKS
  boolean checkRemotely()
  {
    char url[30];
    sprintf(url, "%s%s", "/arduino.php?pass=", password);
    // TODO: Fix requests not begin completed most of the time
    printlnData(url, true);
    if (arduinoHttpClient.get(url) == 0)
    {
      if (arduinoHttpClient.responseStatusCode() == 200)
      {
        arduinoHttpClient.responseBody();
        printlnData(F("INFO Password accepted."), true);
        return true;
      }
      else if (arduinoHttpClient.responseStatusCode() == 404)
      {
        arduinoHttpClient.responseBody();
        printlnData(F("INFO Password rejected."), true);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN_RED, HIGH);
        return false;
      }
    }
    delay(500);
  }

  //... MAIN PROGRAM
  void setup()
  {
    Ethernet.begin(MAC_ADDR, ARDUINO_IP /*, gateway, subnet*/);
    arduinoServer.begin();
    initSD();
    initKeypad();
    door(DOOR_CLOSE);
    if (DEBUG != 0)
    {
      printlnData(F("INFO Version 1.3.1"), true);
      printData(F("INFO Arduino IP = "), true);
      IPAddress ip = Ethernet.localIP();
      printlnData(String() + ip[0] + "." + ip[1] + "." + ip[2] + "." + ip[3], false);
    }

    arduinoHttpClient = HttpClient(arduinoClient, DB_SERVER_ADDR, 80);
    delay(100);
    if (arduinoHttpClient.available())
    {
      printlnData(F("INFO Initial Connection Succeded!"), true);
      if (MODE == 0)
      {
        printlnData(F("INFO Initialized as Data Download Mode"), true);
        downloadClients();
      }
      else
      {
        printlnData(F("INFO Initialized as Remote Check Mode"), true);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printlnData(F("WARN Initial Connection Failed!"), true);
      if (MODE == 0)
        reconnect(true);
    }
    cute.play(S_MODE3);
  }

  void loop()
  {
    websitePresentation();
    keypadInputProccessor();
    if (MODE == 0)
      updateLocalData();
  }
  ```
- Server Side Scripts, pay special attention to the data organization and the headers begin set and compare them with the above `downloadClients` function.

  ```php
  <?php
      $dbhost = 'localhost';
      $dbuser = 'yourUser';
      $dbpass = 'yourPass';
      $dbname = 'yourDB';

  $data = "";
  $conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
      $ingresos = $_GET['ingresos'];
          $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT p.id AS '*', pa.id_cliente AS 'ID Paciente', concat(pa.nombre, pa.apellido) AS 'Nombre', pa.cuil AS 'CUIL', p.momento AS 'Marca Temporal' FROM pases p INNER JOIN pacientes pa ON pa.id_cliente = p.paciente ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT " . $ingresos);
      }

      if (!empty($resultados) and mysqli_num_rows($resultados) > 0) {
          $total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultados);

          $index = 1;
          while ($index <= $total_registros) {
              $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);
              if (!$debug) {
                  $data .= '<tr>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['*'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['ID Paciente'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['Nombre'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['CUIL'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['Marca Temporal'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '</tr>';
              } else {
                  $data .= '<tr>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['*'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['Nombre Cliente'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['CUIL'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['Estado'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '<td>' . $fila['Abono'] . '</td>';
                  $data .= '</tr>';
              }
              $index++;
          }
          mysqli_free_result($resultados);
          header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 200', true, 200);
          header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      } else {
          header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 404', true, 404);
          header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      }
      mysqli_close($conexion);
      echo $data;
  ```